# jQuery image src change by height

Tags: jquery

I have to refresh a web project with a large picture archive. I would like to exchange all the pictures, that have less than a certain height (let's say 400px), by a fallback image. Can this be solved with jQuery? For example

```
<div class="container">     
    <img src="test/testimage-300x280.jpg" height="280" width="300">
</div>
```

Should become:

```
<div class="container">     
    <img src="images/img_fallback.png">
</div>
```

It's about the thumbnails on the overview pages of a WordPress installation. The new thumbnails will be relatively large, so I need the alignment. Currently vary the heights, when an original image is smaller than the minimum height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to achieve this:

```
$('.container img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).height() < 400;
}).prop('src', 'images/img_fallback.png').removeAttr('width height');
```

Comment: That solved it, thank you for your super quick response!